# Where is the sql syntax error?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert

it returns that I made a syntax error in my SQL statement cant find where, I used this syntax earlier and it worked... could you tell me where it is please ?

```
     public static void addKc(KeyCeremony kc)
    {
        string ka = kc.ka;
        string kc1 = kc.kc1;
        string kc3 = kc.kc3;
        string family = kc.family;
        string so = kc.so;
        string it = kc.it;
        string desc = kc.desc;




        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connecString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO KC(Family, Kc1, Kc3, Ka, So, It, Desc) VALUES(@Family, @Kc1, @Kc3, @Ka, @So, @It, @Desc)";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Family", family);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kc1", kc1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kc3", kc3);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ka", ka);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@So", so);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@It", it);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", desc);


                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Insertion OK");

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

    }
    }
```

hope you will find it faster than me

Comment: `Desc` is a keyword. Add brackets: `[Desc]`

Comment: Can you put the error information in the question?

Comment: Thanks Erik !
Hendry, the problem was the protected keyword..

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: It'd be great if you put that comment in an answer so OP could accept it.

Comment: @ChristianLundahl I'm voting to close this as a simple typo instead. There are also many, many dupes of this error.

Comment: Also,  need to bear in mind that ["The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement ... In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Desc` is a keyword. Change to this: `[Desc]`.

**All Keywords in SQL**:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words